# Return from loop but the execution of loop not effects?

Tags: c#, php, loops, iterator, recursive-query

Is is possible in php when return some value from loop and execution of loop still continues from next index (like GetEnumerator() in C# and the use MoveNext())

problem-

```
$arr=[0,1,5,9,5];
$i=count($arr);
while($i>0){
    // data base operations
    $_GLOBALS['i']=$_GLOBALS['i']-1;
    //return some value;
}
```

I am a c# programmer and new to php so any help or ideas would be highly appreciated ?

Comment: The short awser is No.

Comment: Please give the code C# or the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can. What you are looking for is the equivalent of the [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) keyword from C#. According to the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php), the same keyword can be used in php to implement a generator.

There is a small example on the documentation page:

> ```
> function gen_one_to_three() {
>     for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
>         // Note that $i is preserved between yields.
>         yield $i;
>     }
> }
>
> $generator = gen_one_to_three();
> foreach ($generator as $value) {
>     echo "$value\n";
> }
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Return as the Control Structures `return` can be used in a function (procedural) or method (Object oriented) to return a value, but this is optional. If you have a loop `while`, `for` `foreach` etc. and you use `return` within, than this would return the value to the calling module and stops the loop.

But there are ways to do a loop and instate of returning it hand it over to a static Object or a global variable.